# Problem with implicitly conversion of string

Tags: c#

I have a object 'currentVersion' of type Data and string variable of 'version',i need to assign what ever things coming  'version' to 'currentVersion'
Code is like this

```
    private static DataVersion currentVersion = new DataVersion();

    string version = this_event.variableData[1].atr_value;

and in internal layers 
public SPD_variableData[] variableData;
and 
      /// <summary>
      /// Definition of variable data for events.
      /// </summary>
      public struct SPD_variableData
      {
         /// <summary>
         /// attribute name 
         /// </summary>
         public string attribute;
         /// <summary>
         /// attribute value
         /// </summary>
         public string atr_value;
      }
```

but when i did currentVersion = version ; i am getting error like this "Error   1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'Safe.Model.Data' "
if that is the case how i can assign values coming on version to currentVersion

Comment: Your `Data` is a type and the object is `currentVersion`, try to use `this_test.currentVersion[1].value`, not `this_test.Data[1].value`.

Comment: We just can't guess what your code looks like. Please post the relevant parts of Data.

Comment: I need to pass string 'version to 'currentVersion'..version is coming from internal layers possibly from clients

Comment: I really want to help you, but we need to know what Data looks like (and possibly what it represents: Data is not a very descriptive name). Without that we can't guess how to create one from a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot convert a string to any old object - in .NET any old object can be turned into a string using the ToString method though.

If you are storing something meaningful in the string that you think you convert into a Data object, then write a method to instantiate a Data object from the string. For example:

```
public static Data FromString(string input)
{
//get something meaningful from the string. eg. if it is a CSV, use split
Data ret = new Data();
string[] fields = input.Split(',');
ret.property1 = fields[0];
ret.property2 = fields[1];
return ret;
}
```

Or was there a reason you thought you could turn a string into a Data object?

### Update

Something like this?

```
public static DataVersion FromVariableData(SPD_variableData input)
{
    //set the properties of a new object before returning it
    DataVersion ret = new DataVersion();
    ret.attribute = input.attribute;
    ret.atr_value = input.atr_value;
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: I think my answer still applies - if you are trying to assign a string to a DataVersion object, you will have to write a conversion method of some kind.

Why do you think that `currentVersion = version` should work?

Comment: Can you make conversion method more clear based on my edited question

Answer (score 0):

First of all Data doesn't seem to be an array...
Second: which type is **value**?
**EDITED:**
you changed your code: what is **level**? It doesn't seem related to **Data**...

Comment: Value is type of SPD_variableData[] ie           /// list of of attribute pairs
         /// </summary>
         public SPD_variableData[] level;